# CS50-HALF Practice Problem - What can I do to troubleshoot my code, which is functioning properly but not producing the desired output?

Tags: c, cs50

CS50 Practice Problem HALF -

[Background](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/1/half/#background)

Suppose you are eating out at a restaurant with a friend and want to split the bill evenly. You may want to anticipate the amount you’ll owe before the bill arrives with tax added. In this problem, you’ll complete a funtion to calculate the amount each of        you owes based on the bill amount, the tax, and the tip.

[Implementation Details](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/1/half/#implementation-details)

Your function should use the input parameters, `bill`, `tax`, and `tip`, to calculate the final amount. However, since these values are percentages, you’ll have to do some work to convert these to more appropriate formats to use for your calculation.

The final amount due, should add the tax to the bill before calculating the tip. Finally, you will return exactly half of the full amount, including the bill amount, the tax and the tip.

### [Thought Question](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/1/half/#thought-question)

- Why do you think there are different data types in C?

### [How to Test Your Code](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/1/half/#how-to-test-your-code)

Your program should behave per the examples below.

```
half/ $ ./half
Bill before tax and tip: 12.50
Sale Tax Percent: 8.875
Tip percent: 20
You will owe $8.17 each!
```

```
half/ $ ./half
Bill before tax and tip: 23.50
Sale Tax Percent: 7  
Tip percent: 15
You will owe $14.46 each!
```

```
half/ $ ./half
Bill before tax and tip: 100
Sale Tax Percent: 6.25
Tip percent: 18
You will owe $62.69 each!
```

This is the code that i wrote -

```
// Calculate your half of a restaurant bill
// Data types, operations, type casting, return value

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");

    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent));
}

// TODO: Complete the function
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float total = (bill + (bill * (tax / 100)) + (bill * (tip * .01))) / 2;
    return ((int)(total * 100.0 + 0.5) / 100.0);
}
```

All that has to be done in this problem is to complete the half function the rest was already given. I completed the function and can’t see anything wrong but it is not giving the required output . Every single required output is wrong .

For example the above three examples that are given in the problem outputs-

1-

```
You will owe $8.05 each!
```

2-

```
You will owe $14.34 each!
```

3-

```
You will owe $62.13 each!
```

Here are the outputs that were required and what i got - https://submit.cs50.io/check50/8bbdc3f80441100b5f1a4e842ef6efe1b7f443fd

```
## cs50/labs/2023/x/half
```

---

```
### :) half.c exists
```

Log

```
checking that half.c exists...

### :) half.c compiles
```

Log

```
running clang half.c -o half -std=c11 -ggdb -lm -lcs50...

### :( Bill of $50, with 10% tax and 20% tip, creates output of $33.00
```

**Cause**

```
expected "33.00", not "You will owe $..."
```

Log

```
running ./half...  
sending input 50...  
sending input 10...  
sending input 20...  
checking for output "33.00"...  
**Expected Output:**  
33\.00**Actual Output:**  
You will owe $32.50 each!

### :( Bill of $50, with 12.5% tax and 20% tip, creates output of $33.75
```

**Cause**

```
expected "33.75", not "You will owe $..."
```

Log

```
running ./half...  
sending input 50...  
sending input 12.5...  
sending input 20...  
checking for output "33.75"...
```

**Expected Output:**

```
33\.75**Actual Output:**  
You will owe $33.13 each!

### :( Bill of $100, with 12.5% tax and 15% tip, creates output of $64.69
```

**Cause**

```
expected "64.69", not "You will owe $..."
```

Log

```
running ./half...  
sending input 100...  
sending input 12.5...  
sending input 15...  
checking for output "64.69"...
```

**Expected Output:**

```
64\.69
```

**Actual Output:**

```
You will owe $63.75 each!
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Naar3.jpg)

Comment: Also, you're using floating-point math for currency - that's a bad idea.  You need **exact** results, and floating-point calculations don't provide that.  See [**Is floating point math broken?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)  Even if you can get the correct answers with these problems for this question, you won't get correct answers in all problems.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it is cs50. They do not go so deep into it. They just started learning C

Comment: Re “functioning properly but not producing the desired output”: That is not what “functioning properly” means.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it another form of saying: "It compiles and links" as usually it is a first significant obstacle

Comment: One must **read** the specs carefully. `"The final amount due, should add the tax to the bill before calculating the tip."` ... The code above does not include the tax when calculating the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply split one lonng hard to read equation into smaller bits:

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float total = bill * ( 1 + tax/100.0);
    total = total * (1 + tip/ 100.0);
    return total /2;
}
```

Isn't it easier to read and understand? Compiler does not care.

Make your life easier when debug and do not user input - just create some test cases. It will save you plenty time

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(50.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f));
    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(50.0f, 12.5f, 20.0f));
    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(100.0f, 12.5f, 15.0f));
}

// TODO: Complete the function
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float total = bill * ( 1 + tax/100.0);
    total = total * (1 + tip/ 100.0);
    return total /2;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fzvo8e5zq

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by breaking it up as such,

```
float bt = (bill + (bill * (tax / 100)));
float total = (bt +(bt * (tip / 100))) / 2;
return total;
```

The issue was that the sum of bill and tax were not being multiplied by the tip amount. You were using the original bill amount in your equation leading to smaller sums. I know this is about a year late but for the future coders.

Comment: I do believe there are two possible outcomes for the total, depending upon what is customary.  For some, a tip is calculated on the bill before the tax, which would be "total = bill + bill * tax / 100 + bill * tip / 100".  For others, who would include the tax with the bill for the tip calculation, it would be as you have in your calculations.  Just throwing that out there as a possible alternative.